# How to add a Dynamic image instead of notification icon in android?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I used below code for displaying notification in notification  Bar.

it worked fine.

But i need to display notification icon dynamically that will come from web service.

How i can do?

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.image,"status message", System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent in = new Intent(Notify.this,CommentU.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(Notify.this, 0, in, 0);
        note.setLatestEventInfo(Notify.this,"NotificationTitle", "You have a new Commentio", pi);
        note.number = ++count;
        note.vibrate = new long[] { 500l, 200l, 200l, 500l };
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have a look at this sample http://code4reference.com/2012/07/android-jelly-bean-notification/

Answer (score 2):

I have one suggestion for you: you have to download that image which you want to show and then you can set that as bitmap: check below code. I have created one `BITMAP`. 
its look link :

[image]

for this you have to add `android-support-v4.jar`

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification").setLargeIcon(BITMAP)
                .setContentText("Hello World!");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, test.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(test.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

for more detail chekc this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

**Removing notifications**

Notifications remain visible until one of the following happens:

The user dismisses the notification either individually or by using "Clear All" (if the notification can be cleared).

The user clicks the notification, and you called `setAutoCancel()` when you created the notification.
You call `cancel()` for a specific notification ID. This method also deletes ongoing notifications.

You call `cancelAll()`, which removes all of the notifications you previously issued.

**Edited:** just replace this.

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification").setLargeIcon(BITMAP)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But,how can i disappear notification from notification Bar when click on that.

Comment: I used setAutoCanel() method to disaapear.

Answer (score 0):

just add some icons in your resource folder and then

`int myIcon = R.drawable.image;`

your logic goes here ....

and change value of icon according to your logic like `myIcon = R.drawable.somenewimage;`

and then finally set your notification

`Notification note = new Notification(myIcon,"status message", System.currentTimeMillis());`