# Use a downloaded image as a notification icon

Tags: android

I am trying to download an image from a URL and then post a notification in the notification drawer with that image. I am operating in the context of an `IntentService`, so I am using simple synchronous image fetching:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
  try {
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
        .openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Now that I have the image downloaded, how would I go about using it for a notification? The problem is that `NotificationCompat.Builder.setSmallIcon(int)` takes an integer ID. For example, something like `R.drawable.my_cool_image`.

Since I downloaded my image dynamically from the web, I do not have an ID for it. How would I use it as the notification icon?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738800/how-to-add-a-dynamic-image-instead-of-notification-icon-in-android Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot set small icons from downloaded images, only the big icon in the actual notification bar using .setLargeIcon(myBitmap);